# How to submit error reports to developer?

Tags: vb.net, submit, runtime-error, error-reporting

How can I submit error reports to the developer (me) when coding in VB.NET?

I have made a Google Forms response form [here](https://docs.google.com/forms/d/1hy6eYwvxzOoLWbSZ-oKH9Gomqvs-bmYKKyQQvlEVfKk/viewform). Is it possible to use the WebBrowser Control functions to paste a string into the TextBox in there and then click the button to submit it, all automatically?

Would it be better to use a different submission form service than this? I know that it uses complicated JavaScript to code everything. If it would be better to use a custom HTML website, how would you interact with that (I can probably figure out how to code the HTML itself)?

All help welcome!

Comment: An old fashioned log file sent via e-mail is too old style?

Comment: No, as long as you can tell me how to integrate this with minimum user effort!

Comment: I have no code to offer for this, but suppose that you add a button in the error page of your app that copy the error message in the body of an email with configuration stored on the server side and send it. The user has only to press the button. Then if you have already an infrastructure to write a log file you could also add an attachment to the mail to get all the story.

Comment: Exactly this is what I'm struggling with..... (writing the code to send the data I already made)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, this was my solution: use System.Net.Mail and MailMessage and SMTP Credentials to send an email to the developer.